# Can't Determine When User Doesn't Allow Location Services

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm requesting the user to turn on location services. I want to know when a user clicks `Don't Allow` so I can handle some notifications. However, the `didFailWithError` or `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` methods are not being called when I click `Don't Allow`. I know this nothing is printed in the logger. I've attached a code sample. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation

class AwesomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if(authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .AuthorizedAlways) {
            // authorization is good
        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print(status)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {            
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `didFailWithError` or `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` methods are not being called

Those are *delegate* methods. Your location manager does not have any delegate - certainly it does not have *you* (the AwesomeViewController instance) as a delegate. So it is not going to call those methods, ever. You need to *set* the location manager's delegate (in this case you would set it to `self`).